# Topologist sine curve and sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to 0$, but $f(x_n) \nrightarrow f(0)$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \sin \frac1x, x \ne 0 \\0, x=0 \end{cases}.$$ Find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to 0$, but $f(x_n) \nrightarrow f(0)$.

Let $x_n = \frac1n$. Now $x_n \to 0$ and $$f(\frac1n)=\begin{cases} \sin n, \frac1n \ne 0 \\0, \frac1n=0 \end{cases}$$
but $\frac1n \ne 0$ ever so $f(x_n) \nrightarrow f(0).$ Is this a valid assumption to make?

Comment: '$\frac1n \ne 0$ ever so $f(x_n) \nrightarrow f(0)$' is not a valid argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nice idea, but it is not properly elaborated.

1. The equation $f(\frac1n)= 0, \frac1n=0 $ does not make any sense because $\frac1n$ is never $0$. But you have $f(x_n)  = f(\frac1n)= \sin n$.
2. It is not clear what you want to say with "but $\frac1n \ne 0$ ever so $f(x_n) \nrightarrow f(0)$". Do you perhaps refer to 1.?
3. You have to verify that $f(x_n) = \sin n \nrightarrow 0 = f(0) $. This is true, but it is not trivial to prove it. Actually no integer is a zero of $\sin$, but this does not a priori exclude that $\sin n \rightarrow 0$.

So what to do? We know that $\sin t_n = 1$ for $t_n = 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$. Now take $x_n= \frac{1}{t_n}$.

Comment: So $t_n \to 0$, but $\sin(\frac{1}{t_n})$ seems to diverge?

Comment: @Siro No, by construction $\sin(t_n)=1$ for all $n$ so it trivially converges to $1$.